# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar la ventana inicial de Mbrola Synthesizer?

Tags: python, windows

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con OCR. Estoy usando el sintetizador Mbrola descargado desde [aquí](http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/mbrcopybin.html). Cuando llamo a la aplicación desde mi código, se muestra la [ventana](http://www.dropbox.com/s/z2l5e6w5rgrkwyc/mbrola1.png?dl=0) inicial. Quiero ocultar ésta ventana porque el código se mantiene en pausa hasta que yo acepte los términos y condiciones de la aplicación dando clic en *I agree*. Lo que deseo es evitar esta ventana y saltar directamente a la aplicación.

He incluído funciones del modulo `pyautogui` para controlar el mouse y que éste de clic en el botón *I agree* automáticamente pero no trabaja. He probado las funciones por separado en un archivo `.py` exclusivo y funcionan perfectamente, pero si a este archivo lo convierto en un subprograma e introduzco una función para llamarla desde el programa principal tampoco funciona.

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
from pytesser import *
import pyttsx
import pyautogui

image=Image.open('process.tiff')
text=image_to_string(image, lang="spa")
print unicode(text)
engine = pyttsx.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate-110)

#funciones del modulo pyautogui
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.moveTo(615, 505) #coordenadas del boton I agree de TTSApp
pyautogui.click()          #en resolucion de pantalla 1366x768
#----------------

engine.say(text)
engine.runAndWait()
```

`pyttsx.init()` está llamando a la aplicación.

Estoy trabajando en Windows con Python 2.7. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Eso de 'no trabaja' a qué se refiere? ¿No cierra la pantalla inicial?, ¿la cierra pero luego no ejecuta el resto del programa python como esperas?, ¿te sale algún mensaje de error en la consola?,...

Comment: 'No trabaja' hace referencia a que no actúan las funciones del modulo `pyautogui`. No se mueve el mouse, tampoco da clic por ende no cierra la pantalla inicial que deseo. A diferencia; cuando ejecuto estas funciones por separado, se ejecutan sin problemas. No se muestra ningún error en consola.

Answer (score 0):

existen paquetes para automatizar el escritorio. Podrías usar, por ejemplo, [pyautogui](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI), [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/), pywin32 (ya lo debes tener instalado si estás en windows),...

Un ejemplo con pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150) ####### AQUÍ TENDRÁS QUE METER LA POSICIÓN DEL BOTÓN
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: He probado el código y funciona cuando lo ejecuto directamente desde un archivo `.py` que tiene unicamente este código pero cuando llamo a ejecutarlo como función dentro de un subprograma, no trabaja. El mouse no se mueve y por ende tampoco realiza el clic.

Comment: Abre una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema o actualiza esta y añade el código.